# htaccess: Редирект с урлов типа site.ru/?amp;id=ХХ на главную

Tags: регулярные-выражения, .htaccess

В файле .htaccess пытаюсь сделать редирект с урлов типа `http://site.ru/?amp;id=ХХ&catid=XX` на главную страницу, т.е. на `http://site.ru/`, но не получается. Пробовал так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^amp;id=(\d+)&catid=(\d+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/$ http://site.ru/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: по крайней мере, RewriteRule не получает ведущий слэш, чтоб завернуть всё, напишите, например, `RewriteRule ^ http://site.ru/ [R=301,L]` А если только пустой uri, то `RewriteRule ^$ http://site.ru/ [R=301,L]`

Comment: Попробуйте это 

    ^(http://site.ru/)/(.*?)$  index.php [R=301,L]

Answer (score 1):

Используйте такую конструкцию для редиректа:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \bid=\d+\b [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \bcatid=\d+\b [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://site.ru/? [R=301,L]
```

Отдельные правила для переменных `id` и `catid` ввел, чтобы не было привязки к порядку следования. Тут же используются границы `\b` для исключения срабатывания правил на часть строки, например на `pid=11gg`. В `RewriteRule` используется `^$` для реакции только на url вида `http://site.ru/?...`, а знак вопроса в адресе сайта тут же для удаления переменных при переадресации.